# How to filter out blank lines in text file - Spark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a text file called "ds_text_file" and I'm trying to filter out the blank lines (between some of the paragraphs of text, there are blank lines). I have tried a few different ways to do this, but it's not working and I'm drawing a blank. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Here is what makes sense to me that I've tried:

```
lines = sc.textFile(ds_text_file)

filteredLines = lines.filter(lambda x: len(x)>0)
```

I have also tried:

```
lines = sc.textFile(ds_text_file)

filteredLines = lines.filter(lambda x: len(x.split())>0)
```

Comment: Blank lines are mostly presented as `\n`. So try to filter for that. Note that ``\n` is a line break, so it is at the end of every line. You want to remove the lines that have this only and no other text.

Comment: Hi @Japhei, thanks for this information. I'm pretty new to programming, and VERY new to Spark, so my question might be very beginner-ish. I know about the \n being the line break, but the lambda function is very confusing for me. How would I use \n in my filter, or do I even need lambda in my filter?

Comment: Can you provide some more code and some sample data for me to reproduce this?

Comment: Why do you think it is not working can you show a case where you feel it should not be the case, I have run this and empty lines are filtered with the function that you have provided

Answer (score 0):

Your empty lines most likely contain white characters like spaces or tabs.

Try this to filter out any line containing only white space:

```py
filteredLines = sc.textFile(ds_text_file)\
    .filter(lambda x: re.match('^\s*$', x) is None)
```